# Unique agents across application instances and BEAM

Tags: erlang, elixir, agent, gen-server

My requirement is to use named agents. Basically one agent per record with a custom id. Can we query the Agent's name across application instances and BEAM ? I mean that if we have 2 instances of an app on 2 different BEAM machines we need to make sure that we have only `one` agent per record. Not more. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you may need to use the `Node` module https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Node.html#content and combine it with your local agent name to get a distributed UID. See also the Kernel builtin function `node()` https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#node/0

Answer (score 1):

[`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html) is basically a [`GenServer`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html). The latter has three options to [register it’s name](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration). Both `{:global, term}` *and* `{:via, module, term}` register the name *globally*.

Of course, all the nodes should be connected for this to work.

To make it easier to address globally registered processes, one might use [`Registry`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html), although in this particular case `{:global, name}` should be fine enough.